# How to script a logout while screen is locked?

Tags: terminal, applescript, script, command-line, user-account

I want to log out a user via a shell script, after a delay. However, there's a few other issues:

- User does not have admin and/or root.
- Logout must complete even if screen is locked.

Currently, I'm using the shell commands below to log out:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to log out'
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke return'
```

This works fine if the screen is active, but if the screen is locked, this fails, because it depends on triggering a window, and then firing an Enter keystroke. As a reminder, techniques like killing loginwindow fail because they require root.

I'm not convinced it's possible; any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: When do you want to trigger the log out? After inactivity or on-demand?

Answer (score 1):

Can you get system events to do Shift-Option-Command-q ?? 
something like... (I don't know the exact syntax)

```
'tell application "System Events" to keystroke q with command down option down shift down'
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, for the same reason the other trick doesn't work: it requires a carriage return, which won't happen when the screen is locked.

Comment: This keyboard shortcut doesn't require the user to enter return - it automatically logs you out without any additional interaction. But I don't know if it will work as a script executed while the screen saver is active and locked.